# How can i add the dynamic resource path or endpoint like below

Tags: soapui

How can i add the dynamic resource path or endpoint like below. The packageid is saved in the global properties. It is generated from the first response which runs before this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCBoh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAPui uses different scopes for properties, and when referencing a property you also need to put the right scope. So let's say this property is set at the Global level, then your reference would look like this:

```
\#Global#PackageId
```

The url in your request should then be:

```
https://sandbox-e.signlive.ca/api/packages/${#Global#PackageId}/roles
```

For something this specific you might want to consider using a different scope for the property though. For example Project, TestSuite or TestCase even.

Also, make sure not to forget the dollar sign when you include a property in your url or message like that.

For more information on properties in SOAPui check [here](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/working-with-properties.html)